# A function in my code doesn't seem to be running, can anyone tell why?

Tags: c++, function

I'm building a fairly simple contact book program to sharpen my C++ skills.
Keep in mind I didn't include all my code because this post would then be massive.

The problem I'm facing is that in the area of code shown below, contactCreator() is not actually running when it is reached in the if statement.

```
int mainInput;

ofstream initialStream("contacts.txt", ofstream::app);
initialStream.close();

while(mainInput != -1){
    system("cls");
    logoHeader();
    cout << endl;
    cout << "--- MAIN MENU -----------------" << endl;
    cout << "[0] Create New Contact" << endl;
    cout << "[1] View Existing Contacts" << endl;
    cout << "[2] View or Edit Data Fields" << endl;
    cout << "-------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Press ENTER without inputting" << endl;
    cout << "anything to EXIT Contact Book." << endl;
    cout << "-------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Enter Selection: ";
    mainInput = menuInput();
    if(mainInput == 0){

        //This is the function that isn't running when it's supposed to.
        contactCreator();

    }else if(mainInput == 1){
        contactViewer();
    }else if(mainInput == 2){
        dataFieldViewer();
    }else if(mainInput < -1 || mainInput > 2){
        invalidInputError();
    }
}
return 0;
```

Some Information about contactCreator():

- It's void, so the issue is not lack of return statements according to my limited C++ knowledge.
- I checked to make sure mainInput is 0, and indeed it is.
- The function is declared at the top of the program before the main function. No problem there.
- I checked the spelling for the function's name. All instances are correct to my knowledge.

Can anyone see if I missed something obvious? I'm pretty new to C++, so I couldn't find any syntax error myself. All of the other functions I've created in my program run perfectly.

I tried to search the internet for my problem, but I'm a bit of a loss of how to describe it simply. Why isn't contactCreator() running as expected?

Also, here are the content of the contactCreator() function if that helps. :)

```
string initialName;
ofstream creatorTempStream("temp.txt");

while(initialName != ""){
    system("cls");
    logoHeader();
    cout << endl;
    cout << "--- NEW CONTACT ---------------" << endl;
    cout << "Enter a name for your contact." << endl;
    cout << "-------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Press ENTER without inputting" << endl;
    cout << "anything to go back." << endl;
    cout << "-------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Name: ";
    getline(cin, initialName);
}
```

Let me know if I'm missing any relevant and important information and I'll update the post. Thanks!

Comment: Variables `mainInput` is read before initialization.

Comment: What does `menuInput()` return? Zero, or the value of '0' ?

Comment: The integer value '0' is returned by `menuInput()`. `menuInput()` is my alternative to `cin`, since I hate `cin`.

Comment: `while(initialName != ""){` -> isn't this string always empty at the start of the while loop?

Comment: @AaronBeaudoin - do you mean char '0', or int value 0? Because you're comparing with int value 0, not char '0'.

Comment: Ah yes the while loop in contactCreator() is the issue. I can't believe I missed that. And I mean't int value 0, by the way.

Comment: The reason in 99.99% of the time is you :)

Comment: @AaronBeaudoin - Ok, I had just put that in an answer.

Comment: Don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` starts a new line.

Comment: Please [edit] both your title and text to more clearly reflect what you're asking. *What are some common reasons...* is asking us to speculate (create a list), which is inappropriate here. Your title will also have zero relevant content for the future reader who sees it in a search result. (As far as the reason your particular code isn't working as expected, two minutes with a debugger would allow you to figure that out yourself, and that's less time than you spent writing your post here. Learn to use one.)

Comment: Short answer: Your function ***is*** running, and you should get a debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `menuInput()` returns the right value, the problem is most likely here (unless there is other code before the while loop):

```
string initialName;
ofstream creatorTempStream("temp.txt");

while(initialName != ""){
}
```

`initialName` is empty at the start of the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try stepping through with a debugger? In your function contactCreator(), you are checking for initialName != "" without initializing it. The chances are that the function is running without you noticing it.